# How do I get my form to post to mysql and link back to my homepage when the sumbit button is pressed

Tags: forms, mysqli

This is the code that I have so far. I've tried putting the action event in on both the submit button and the form. But for some reason when I'm getting it back to the Index page it isn't putting anything in my tables.

```
?>
<?php
include('../includes/conn.inc.php');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO registration (firstName, secondName, age, email, username,  password, mailingList) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssisssb', $_POST['firstname'], 
$_POST['surname'],
$_POST['age'],
$_POST['email'],
$_POST['username'],
$_POST['password'],
$_POST['list']);
$stmt->execute();  
$stmt->close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
<link href="../styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<header>
<h1>Register Now</h1>
</header>
<body>
<section>
<form id = "registrationForm" method="post" action = "../checkregistration.php">

<fieldset>
    <p>
        <label for="firstname">First name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /> 
        <span id="surnameReq">*Value Required</span>            
    </p>   
    <p>
        <label for="surname">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
        <span id="surnameReq">*Value Required</span>   
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
        <span id="ageReq">*Value Required</span>   
    </p>      
    <p>
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="Email" />
        <span id="emailReq">*Value Required</span>   
    </p> 
    <p>
        <label for="Username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
        <span id="usernameReq">*Value Required</span>   
    </p>  
    <p>
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
        <span id="passwordReq">*Value Required</span>   
    </p>   
    <p>
        <label for="mailingList">Join mailing list</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="list" id="mailingList" value="1" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="sendButton" action = "../checkregistration.php" />

</fieldset>
</form>
</section>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your method for mysql, I would probably do:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(host, user, password, database);

$query = "INSERT INTO registration (firstName, secondName, age, email, username,  password, mailingList) VALUES (".$_POST['firstname'].", 
    ".$_POST['surname'].",
    ".$_POST['age'].",
    ".$_POST['email'].",
    ".$_POST['username'].",
    ".$_POST['password'].",
    ".$_POST['list'].");"

mysqli_query($conn,$query)

mysqli_close($conn);
```

(put into the ../checkregistration.php file)

You could also add some error handling, and probably hashing the data is a good idea (I won't explain that now, there are many places on the web explaining that).

After that, to link back to the main page:

```
header("Location: /index.php"); // Or whatever the main page is
```